# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when I try to read input using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

I am trying to take a multiple integer input in a single line and store all those integers into an `ArrayList`. This is my code:

```
    String[] input = new String[5]; 

    ArrayList<Integer> A=new ArrayList<>(5);

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
    try{
        while(br.readLine()!=null)
            input = br.readLine().split(" "); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
```

The input is like this :

> 2 2 1 3 1

But when I excecute the code I get a NullPointerException in this line **input = br.readLine().split(" ");**. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** Tried using Scanner to take the input like this:

```
    String str="";
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] input = new String[5]; 
    ArrayList<Integer> A=new ArrayList<>(5);

    
    while(s.hasNext())
        str=s.nextLine();
    
    input=str.split(" ");
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));  //[]
```

Now my array is completely empty!!

Comment: Test the result of `readLine()` before calling `split()` on it.  The javadoc explains when `readLine` returns `null`.

Comment: Did you close `System.in` before running this code?

Comment: consider using a try-with-resources statement or using statement for your readers, depending on your use case.

Comment: The problem is that you are testing if readLine() returns null (eof), then you are calling readlLine() again. This second might return null. You should do the test like ``if ((str = br.readLine()) != null) { ... }``.

Comment: Tried that @NomadMaker, the error is still there

Comment: Do you still have the ``br.readLine()`` inside the body of the while loop?

Comment: Yes @NomadMaker

Comment: Then imagine a case where you have exactly one line in your file. The first readLine() (in the while condition) reads in a single line. Then in the body of the loop you throw that value away and read the second line, which is equal to null because there is no more data in the file. You should only read the line once each time through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You have two calls to `br.readLine()`. While the first call will abort the loop if line is null, the second call can still read the next line which can be null (indicating end of file). Additional problem is also that the line returned by the first `br.readLine()` is lost.

The correct way is:

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] input = line.split(" ");
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, the input[] array shows `[null]`

Comment: Of course, you have to split by space. Fixed.

Comment: when I split by space the input[] array shows `[]`

Comment: Add a `System.out.println(line)` so that you see what you are reading. Post it here.

Answer (score -2):

There should be exactly 1 spaces between the input numbers. Also you should not start input with space or have 2 spaces joined together when you are running this code.

Comment: Or you could change the split to ``split("\\s+")`` which will split on one or more spaces.